# Why does my threading seem to fail after a few threads have started on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I have this code in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate call:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[webUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    CMTime timeduration = playerItem.duration;
    float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeduration);
    NSString *duration = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", seconds];

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UITableViewCell *updatecell = [tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        updatecell.detailTextLabel.text = duration;
        [updatecell setNeedsLayout];
    });
});
```

Each cell slowly, in the background, loads up the `seconds` into the `updatecell.detailTextLabel.text` on the cell. The problem is after I scroll, after about 3 or 4 cells loaded, the rest just show 0 in the detailTextLabel quickly and don't load.

Any ideas why this is? Am I not doing my threading correctly?

Comment: You should consider using a model object to store the data on `dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(),` and then while table cell is reloading, you should read from that model object and show the text in `detailTextLabel`. The above code will not work if the cell is not visible at the time `dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue()` executes.

Comment: Can you give me an example in code of what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Many servers impose a constraint of how many concurrent requests they accept from a given client. I'd suggest you use `NSOperationQueue` to constrain how many concurrent requests you make of your server to 4 or 5, rather than using dispatch queues.
2. You're potentially making the issue worse than it needs to be, because if you scroll the table view down and then back up, when you redisplay the first few cells, you're re-downloading the `AVPlayerItem` and trying to make additional concurrent requests of your server. You really should save the results of your previous downloads, to eliminate the need for redundant re-requests of the same data.
3. You're not currently checking to see if the cell that just downloaded is still visible before trying to update the UI. You really should check that.

So, I might suggest the following:

1. In your view controller's `viewDidLoad`, create the `NSOperationQueue` that we'll use for downloading. Also specify how many concurrent operations your server will permit:

   ```
   downloadQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   downloadQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4; // replace this with an appropriate value for your server
   ```
2. Before, you had an array, `webUrls`, which was an array of `NSURL` objects. In point #4, below, we'll discuss retiring that array, and create a new array of row objects. But before we can do that, we should create this new `RowData` object.

   Each row object will have not only the `webURL`, but also other things, such as the `durationText` and perhaps even the `AVPlayerItem` itself. (By keeping these other object properties, when a cell scrolls back into view, we don't need to re-download the data.) So the public interface for this new class might look like:

   ```
   //
   //  RowData.h
   //

   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

   @class AVPlayerItem;

   @interface RowData : NSObject

   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *webURL;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *durationText;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
   @property (nonatomic, getter = isDownloaded, readonly) BOOL downloaded;
   @property (nonatomic, getter = isDownloading, readonly) BOOL downloading;

   - (void)downloadInQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))block;
   - (void)cancelDownload;

   @end
   ```

   By the way, I'm not crazy about the class name, `RowData`. It's a little too ambiguous. But I don't know enough about the nature of your model data to suggest a better name. Feel free to call this class whatever you think is appropriate.
3. Your new `RowData` class can have an instance method, called `downloadInQueue`, that performs the download, sets the `durationText` appropriately, etc. By moving the download logic here, we successfully isolate `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from some of the gory details involved with downloading. Just as importantly, though, this `downloadInQueue` method won't update the user interface itself, but rather it has `completion` block provided by `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (demonstrated in point #5, below), so this `downloadInQueue` method doesn't have to worry about UI considerations. Anyway, the implementation of `downloadInQueue` might look like:

   ```
   //
   //  RowData.m
   //

   #import "RowData.h"
   #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

   @interface RowData ()

   @property (nonatomic, getter = isDownloaded) BOOL downloaded;
   @property (nonatomic, getter = isDownloading) BOOL downloading;
   @property (nonatomic, weak) NSOperation *operation;

   @end

   @implementation RowData

   - (void)downloadInQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion
   {
       if (!self.isDownloading)
       {
           self.downloading = YES;

           NSOperation *currentOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
               BOOL success = NO;

               self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:self.webURL];
               if (self.playerItem)
               {
                   success = YES;
                   CMTime timeduration = self.playerItem.duration;
                   float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeduration);
                   self.durationText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", seconds];
               }
               self.downloading = NO;
               self.downloaded = YES;

               [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                   completion(success);
               }];
           }];

           [queue addOperation:currentOperation];
           self.operation = currentOperation;
       }
   }

   - (void)cancelDownload
   {
       if ([self isDownloading] && self.operation)
       {
           self.downloading = NO;
           [self.operation cancel];
       }
   }

   @end
   ```
4. In your main view controller, rather than creating your old array of `webUrls`, create a new array of these `RowData` objects called, for example, `objects`. Set the `webURL` property for each of those `RowData` objects, of course. (Again, I'm not crazy about the ambiguous name of `objects`, but I don't know enough about your app to make a more specific suggestion. Call this whatever you want. But my code below will use `objects`.)
5. Finally, modify your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to use this new `RowData` object and it's `downloadInQueue` method. Also, note, the `completion` block checks to make sure the cell is still visible:

   ```
   RowData *rowData = self.objects[indexPath.row];

   if ([rowData isDownloaded])
   {
       cell.detailTextLabel.text = rowData.durationText;
   }
   else
   {
       cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"..."; // you really should initialize this so we show something during download or remove anything previously there

       [rowData downloadInQueue:self.downloadQueue completion:^(BOOL success) {
           // note, if you wanted to change your behavior based upon whether the 
           // download was successful or not, just use the `success` variable

           UITableViewCell *updateCell = [tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

           // by the way, make sure the cell is still on screen

           if (updateCell)
           {
               updateCell.detailTextLabel.text = rowData.durationText;
               [updateCell setNeedsLayout];
           }
       }];
   }
   ```
6. If using iOS 6, if you want to cancel pending downloads when a cell scrolls off the screen, you can use the `didEndDisplayingCell` method of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

   ```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       RowData *rowData = self.objects[indexPath.row];

       if ([rowData isDownloading])
           [rowData cancelDownload];
   }
   ```

   If supporting earlier versions of iOS, you'd have to use `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol methods, such as [`scrollViewDidScroll`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a), determine which cells have scrolled off the screen (e.g. are not included in `indexPathsForVisibleRows`) manually, but the idea is the same.

By the way, in my sample `RowData` above, I'm saving the `AVPlayerItem`. You should only do that if you need the `AVPlayerItem` later. We've saved the `duration`, which achieves all we need for the `UITableViewCell`, but I assume you might later want to do something with the `AVPlayerItem`, so I save that, too. But if you're not going to need that `AVPlayerItem` later, then don't save it in the `RowData` object. Also, I don't know how big those are, but you might want to write a `didReceiveMemoryWarning` that will iterate through your `objects` and set each item's `playerItem` object to `nil`.

Comment: I actually am already saving duration so I don't hit the server constantly, I just didn't show it in my posted code because I wanted to focus on the issue of the threads returning 0. Anyway, I will try your ideas today and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: +1, for recommending the usage of model objects in this scenario.

Comment: OK update on this... it appears to be working great, but how do I cancel the  operation is the cell is no longer visible? Each operation takes about 1 second to complete, and when I scroll quickly through 1500 cells, it takes forever for the duration to show up on the visible cells at the bottom on the TableView. I want ONLY the current visible cells to download the duration. How?

Comment: Another advantage of operation queues, because you can cancel the individual operations. So, when initiating a download, instead of `addOperationWithBlock`, create a `NSBlockOperation` with `blockOperationWithBlock` and then do `[queue addOperation:operation]`. But also maintain a pointer to that operation as a `weak` property of `RowData`. Then you can now check to see if the download is in progress, and if so, `cancel` on that operation. By the way, cancel downloads actively running, but can cancel pending downloads.

Comment: tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath: will work for me perfectly, but what is the code to call to cancel the operation within my object?

Comment: Thanks! Everything is working great now. You have been a HUGE help and I can't thank you enough.... learned a lot!