# How do I cancel an NSOperation in my object when my UITableViewCell is no longer visible?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsoperation

Is my `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate I have the following code:

```
if ([movie isDownloaded])
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = movie.duration;
else
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";

    [movie downloadInQueue:self.downloadQueue completion:^(BOOL success) {

        UITableViewCell *updateCell = [tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];            
        if (updateCell)
        {
            updateCell.detailTextLabel.text = movie.duration;
            [updateCell setNeedsLayout];
        }
    }];
}
```

Which calls into Movie.m and runs this code:

```
- (void)downloadInQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion
{
    if (!self.isDownloading)
    {
        self.downloading = YES;

        [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            BOOL success = NO;

            AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:self.fileURL];
            CMTime timeduration = playerItem.duration;
            float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeduration);
            self.duration = [self timeFormatted:seconds];

            self.downloading = NO;
            self.downloaded = YES;
            success = YES;

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                completion(success);
            }];
        }];
    }
}
```

When my cells become **not** visible, I want to cancel the `NSOperation` in the `Movie` object if it hasn't been run yet (remove it from the queue). I know I can subclass `UITableViewCell` and do something like this:

```
- (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow
{
    [super willMoveToWindow:newWindow];

    if (newWindow==nil) {
            // Cell is no longer in window so cancel from queue
    }
}
```

Question... how can I cancel my `Movie` `NSOperation` from within the `UITableViewCell` delegate call? With a delegate or `NSNotification` of some kind? I need to know the `indexPath` of the cell to get the correct Movie object out of my array and cancel the operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of iOS 6 you can use the tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of the [UITableView Delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  This gets called when the cell is removed from the table view (which happens when it is no longer visible).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Cancel operation here for cell at indexPath
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By the way, I just saw this question here, but already answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14425596/1271826). But I agree with Nebs (and his answer should be accepted).

As Nebs said, in iOS 6, use `didEndDisplayingCell`. Thus, it might look like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Movie *movie = self.movies[indexPath.row];

    if ([movie isDownloading])
        [movie cancelDownload];
}
```

But in earlier versions, you have to do something like responding to [`scrollViewDidScroll`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a), manually looking at what `indexPath` objects are no longer included in `indexPathsForVisibleRows`, and cancel operations from there

In order to cancel the operation, you need to change this `downloadInQueue` so that rather than just calling `addOperationWithBlock`, it should create a `NSBlockOperation` and add that to the queue, but also save a `weak` reference to it so you can write the `cancelDownload` method like so:

```
@interface Movie ()

@property (nonatomic, getter = isDownloaded) BOOL downloaded;
@property (nonatomic, getter = isDownloading) BOOL downloading;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSOperation *operation;

@end

@implementation Movie

- (void)downloadInQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion
{
    if (!self.isDownloading)
    {
        self.downloading = YES;

        NSOperation *currentOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            BOOL success = NO;

            self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:self.webURL];
            if (self.playerItem)
            {
                success = YES;
                CMTime timeduration = self.playerItem.duration;
                float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeduration);
                self.durationText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", seconds];
            }
            self.downloading = NO;
            self.downloaded = YES;

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                completion(success);
            }];
        }];

        [queue addOperation:currentOperation];
        self.operation = currentOperation;
    }
}

- (void)cancelDownload
{
    if ([self isDownloading] && self.operation)
    {
        self.downloading = NO;
        [self.operation cancel];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should pass in either the cell or the index path to `downloadInQueue:completion:`. Then you can maintain the connection between the cell and its operation, either using a dictionary, an array, or associated objects.

Comment: ...or you can use the facilities offered by the framework, as pointed out by Nebs.